# Java: Casting double to int > Integer.MAX_VALUE

Tags: java, primitive-types

I'm trying to do the following problem from "Core Java for the Impatient" -

> "What happens when you cast a double to an int that is larger than
>   the largest possible int value?"

**Code:**

```
package ch01.sec01;
import java.util.Random;

public class Exercise_5{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int max = 10000;
        int min = 1000; 
        Random rand = new Random(); 
        double randomDouble = Integer.MAX_VALUE + rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1);
        System.out.println("randomDouble: " +randomDouble);
        int intFromDouble = (int)randomDouble;
        System.out.println("intFromDouble: " +intFromDouble); 
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
randomDouble: -2.147475257E9
intFromDouble: -2147475257
```

I'm wondering why randomDouble takes a negative value since primitve double has a wider range than primitive int and so there should be no overflow issues and what would be the correct way to get a double greater than Integer.MAX_VALUE?

Thanks

Comment: You're doing int addition -- why would there be no overflow issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the expression:

```
double randomDouble = Integer.MAX_VALUE + rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1);
```

the right hand side of the expression will first assign the sum to an integer, then this result will be cast to a double.  Since adding anything to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` will result in overflow, you end up with a negative number, because the sign bit gets flipped as part of the overflow.

If you want a double, then just cast `MAX_VALUE` to `double`:

```
double randomDouble = (double)Integer.MAX_VALUE + (double)rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1);
```

Now in this case you get what you want, because you are adding a random number to a double, which is bearing the largest int value, which is not near the limit for what doubles can store.

### Demo

Comment: Could you please explain why you import java.lang.* in the demo code? I'm trying to learn Java and wondering if this is some sort of best practice. Thanks,

Comment: @shanlodh Just ignore that if it isn't being used.  The demo puts some default imports at the top.  This isn't relevant to the question (I think).

Comment: @shanlodh, don't use `import java.lang.*;` - that package is accessible from anywhere without any imports

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen if one of the operands is a `double`, then the result of the expression is going to be a `double`. So, 2 casts to `double` are unnecessary, right?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Yes, you're right, but for didactic reasons I thought I would just make everything on the RHS a `double`.  We could also have just called `Random#nextDouble()` as well.

Answer (score 1):

To put it simply: when you execute `double randomDouble = Integer.MAX_VALUE + rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1);` the part that is actually overflowing (as an Integer, thus taking a negative value) is just `Integer.MAX_VALUE + rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1)` which is subsequently casted to double.

Answer (score 1):

Your line does not cast the 2 part as double, and then sum them, but it sum them which results in an overflow, and them you just put in a double

```
double randomDouble = Integer.MAX_VALUE + rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1);
```